# Laravel 5.5 after login redirect to a specific route

Tags: redirect, authentication, laravel-5.5, laravel-blade

I'm trying to do such a simple thing in Laravel 5.5 that I can't believe there's a way to do it.

I have a button that if the user is authenticated it should do something and if the user is not authenticated, it should send the user to the login page, and after the user logs in redirect to another page. How do I pass that other page URL as a parameter to the login page?

My Blade code for that button is:

```
@if(empty($_user))
<a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="button button-reply icon-button reply-icon" title="Post a reply">Post Reply</a>
@else
<a href="#reply-post" class="button button-reply icon-button reply-icon" title="Post a reply">Post Reply</a>
@endif
```

Am I missing something? Is there a way to do such a basic thing? I know that if the final page is protected with the auth middleware Laravel does this redirect, but in this case the page is not behind that middleware.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by passing the final URL to the login page and then include it as  hidden input in the login form to finally use it in the `redirectPath()` function in the LoginController.

This is the code in the page Blade to pass the redirectTo to the login page in the URL:

```
<a href="{{ route('login') }}?redirectTo={{ urlencode(route('topic', $topic->id)) }}" class="button button-reply icon-button reply-icon" title="Post a reply">Post Reply</a>
```

Then in the login form:

```
@if(!empty(app('request')->input('redirectTo')))
<input type="hidden" name="redirectTo" value="{{ urldecode(app('request')->input('redirectTo')) }}" />
@endif
```

And in the `redirectPath()` function:

```
/**
 * If there's a defined redirectTo, use it
 */
if (!empty(request()->input('redirectTo'))) {
    $this->redirectTo = request()->input('redirectTo');
}
```

And this is working fine for me, but I still believe Laravel should have a built-in solution for this, so if anyone knows a built-in solution, or a better way to solve this please share here!